# Is it good practice to write a test that waits for 31 mins to cover expiration scenarios?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, robotium

I've written the ff. behavior test. Is writing a test that waits for 31 mins to cover expiration scenarios acceptable and good practice?

```
public class ExpiredTokenBehaviorTestCase extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ResetPasswordActivity> {

    protected Solo solo;

    public final static int TOKEN_EXPIRATION_MINS = 31 * 1000 * 60; // 31 minutes, sanity check, can't do math

    public ExpiredTokenBehaviorTestCase() {
        super(ResetPasswordActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }

    /**
     * Expired
     */
    public void testExpiredPassword() {
        solo.typeText(0, "+639224424166"); // type in mobile number to send the verification code
        solo.clickOnButton("Next >"); // click next

        if (solo.waitForActivity(VerificationActivity.class)) {
            solo.typeText(0, "ab2f1de"); // valid code
            solo.sleep(TOKEN_EXPIRATION_MINS); // wait for token to expire
            solo.clickOnButton("Next >"); // now click on next
            solo.waitForText("Verification code expired"); // should show the code expired
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ask whoever is running the test if it is acceptable. Who are we to judge? :-)

Comment: Good point. Will edit question now.

Comment: Personally my test case would mock or change TOKEN_EXPIRATION_MINS to something more manageable and test that it expires when it goes over. Waiting 31 minutes each time you run the test is way too long.

Answer (score 3):

Automated tests should run as fast as possible. The faster they run, the cheaper it is to run them. This way you can have them running frequently and giving you quick feedback on successes and failures. Tests that are fast to execute also keep continuous integration runs short and manageable, which is a valuable bonus.

31 minutes is way too long for a test to give feedback. Instead, you should aim to be able to control the expiration time of your tokens within the tests, and generate a token that expires instantly so that you can test the expiration scenario straight away, without having to wait at all.